# Unable to talk in chat despite enough reputation

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, chat

I am no longer able to participate on chat. Starting today (between 2AM and 1PM CET), something got broken.

[image]

It clearly recognizes me, as clicking the avatar produces:

[image]

But the chat user profile says I have **0** reputation, while it recognizes all my badges:

[image]

Comment: I will request migration to MSO if I'm confident I'm not just doing it wrong. I'd *Ask a Super User moderator*, but I can't :-(

Comment: Already reported on MSO - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117862/eeep-wheres-all-the-rep-gone

Comment: I had this one time, because I blocked some sort of cookies, they werent chocklate chip :-)

Comment: @ChrisF Thanks. I searched on MSO, but that topic is so horribly key worded, no wonder I didn't find it...

Comment: @Psycogeek As I wrote, the site recognizes me and my user profile.

Comment: There are two duplicates there as well with better wording. I might edit the title...

Comment: @ChrisF Then There's the fact that the topics are barely older than mine. I might have searched too early. There wasn't a single topic with "chat" in title or tags on the front page...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed now (as you already noticed); more info [on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/117870/115866).